# Convergence in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ which are continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$. With $|f_n(x)|\leq1$ and $|f_n'(x)|\leq 1$. Then $\{f_n\}$ has a sub sequence that converges in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.

How does this result follow? What would happen if we remove the restriction $|f_n'(x)|\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a consequence of [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).**

As $\Vert f^\prime_n \Vert \le 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ you have applying the mean value theorem $$\vert f_n(x)-f_n(y) \vert \le \vert x - y \vert$$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Which means that the sequence $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous.

Also $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded. That follows from $\Vert f_n \Vert \le 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

The hypothesis of Arzela-Ascoli theorem are fulfilled. Which means that the set of the $f_n$ is relatively compact. Hence there is a convergent subsequence.

**And if you remove the condition $\Vert f_n^\prime \Vert \le 1$**, the conclusion may not hold. Consider the sequence of functions defined by $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1-nx & \text{for } 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try x^{n} or sin( n x).
Bounded derivatives guarantee equicontinuity (for an epsilon you can choose the same delta for all n). Check Ascoli-Arzela.